# Bazel repository rule- downloading a file in repository_ctx.execute

Tags: bazel

I have a java test I'm trying to sandbox which does somewhat of a complex download logic.
I'm thinking of writing a repository rule which will just start a java app using `repository_ctx.execute` to run this logic instead of duplicating it in skylark.

How should I get the contents of this call?
I can pass the java app a path/filename to download the file to but then I'm not sure what path to give it. I can maybe have that print the bytes to stdout and collect them via the exec_result (sounds horrible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`repository_ctx.path("path/to/file")`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/repository_ctx.html#path) that returns a [path](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/path.html) to get a path relative to the generated workspace, then using `path.realpath` you can get a canonical name for the output.

Collecting the output of exec_result to use as a file input should work but it was never tried to my knowledge so there might be weird encoding issue happening.

Comment: That can be a non-existent path right? If I do repo_ctx.path("downloads/MySQL.installer") and ask the tool to download there will it be an output of the rule? Last part is whether a directory can be the output? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the "will it be an output of the rule?" question. This can be an non-existent path and the tool has to create it then.

Comment: NM. I realized the BUILD file I create should declare a file group for the *directory* which will make it an output of the rule. Thanks.